# Как унаследовать только часть класса?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как запретить использование кнопки Tkinter в дочернем классе?

То есть я использую:

```
super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

для наследования части кнопок из другого окна. Но при этом переходят все, а мне нужны только некоторые.

Как это устроить?

Comment: Скрыть кнопку в наследнике?

Comment: Ну, можно и так сказать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл способ решения. Использовал метод `.place_forget` для удаления виджета с окна Tk

Comment: Хорошо, что вы разобрались, но было бы еще лучше, если и в вопросе и в ответе присутствовал минимальный воспроизводимый код. Это будет более наглядно для людей, которые столкнутся с подобной проблемой. P.S. если возник вопрос о "частичном наследовании", скорее всего, присутствуют ошибки проектрирования. Тут, вероятно, лучше было бы добавить еще один слой абстракции и реализовать в нем все, что является строго общим для потомков.